# What are the files with .coffee extension found in the source of Google Chrome plugin Vimium?

Tags: file-extension

What are the files with  .coffee extension found in the source of Google Chrome plugin Vimium?

Thanks for your help

Comment: that is probably be coffeescript file

Answer (score 1):

It's [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). Basically it's a different way of writing JavaScript in a more succinct manner. It has to be "compiled" to JavaScript before it can be ran.